# Excel Conditional Formatting - match or partial match value in other cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want the background in cell A1 to change color if it matches or partially matches the value in cell A2 using Conditional Formatting. For me right now a full match works with `=A1=$A$2`. But if cell A1 has the value 1X and cell A2 has the value 1 or X it doesn't work, only if it would also be 1X. How would I fix this to also include partial matches for the values below?

These are the only allowed values in cell A1: 1, X, 2, 1X, 12, X2, 1X2

These are the only allowed values in cell A2: 1, X, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional formatting rule for `A1` is

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,A1))
```

To limit the possible values in A1 to a limited set, I suggest using `Data Validation`.

Comment: I can't use the code you wrote as I'm getting an error message: "There's a problem with this formula", any idea why? And also I'm already using a Data Validation list for the values in A1.

Comment: @Walter the formula is correct and test. Please make sure you didn't omit some parenthesis or something. Also this is intended to be entered after `Selecting A1` then `Home --> Conditional Formatting --> New Rule --> Use a Formula...`

Comment: No I'm using it correctly, my other code works fine but this doesn't when adding a new rule exactly as you described. Error message: "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula."

Comment: Is your Excel options set to use `R1C1 Reference Style` ?? check it with `File-->Options-->Formulas` to see if that option is checked. Also what is your Excel version?

Comment: `R1C1 Reference Style` was not checked, but it is now, restarted Excel as well, still getting that error message. I'm using Excel 2016 (16.0.8201.2102) 32-bit and English language.

Comment: No no dont check it! I was only trying to figure out why the formula was rejected. The formula is using `A1` reference style and so were your own formulas. Uncheck it again, keep working with `A1` style. That said, I am unfortunately unable to guess why Excel rejects the formula at your side and not at mine :(

Comment: OK, unchecked it. I will keep trying different things and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Walter you are welcome. Please don't hesitate to ask anything further :)

Comment: Finally solved it. My version of Excel expects `;` instead of `,` between values in rules.

Comment: @Walter ah! I never suspected you had a different regional setting. Glad to know that you solved it :)